# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError：accessibilityHitTest

Tags: java, appkit, sikuli-x

I'm using Sikulix 2.0.6.
There is an error in the message field:
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError：accessibilityHitTest

I looked
https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/pull/5702

but still don't know how to fix it.

and my terminal log:
Exception in thread "AppKit Thread" 2021-11-25 23:12:27.606 java[4714:116836] Bad JNI lookup accessibilityHitTest

I use m1 mac.
Is there anyone in a similar situation?

---- updated ------

every time I click IDE , the error line will increase.
And when I change the window size of the ide the error disappears strangely, but when I restart, I get the error again.

[image]

Comment: I've got the same error when running jmeter on a MacBook Pro with the M1 Pro chip. I'm on Monterey 12.0.1 and used Homebrew to install Java (Monterey doesn't include Java out of the box). I can open the jmeter app with `jmeter` from the command line, but trying to open or save files in the app throws the error: 'Exception in thread "AppKit Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: accessibilityHitTest'. Clicking or resizing the app window does not trigger the error.

Comment: Update: solved my issue by running `brew uninstall jmeter`, installing the binaries directly from https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi, and adding the filepath to the jmeter bin folder to my $PATH. You may need to use a different Java and/or Sikulix build.

Answer (score 3):

I found your post because I'm also seeing accessibilityHitTest errors on Mac. In my case, an Intel Mac, using Big Sur v11.6.1. I'm using a java application for boardgaming called [VASSAL](https://vassalengine.org/). The errors appear in the error log whilst a game is being played using VASSAL v3.6.1. That version of VASSAL is using Java 17.0.1.  The error didn't seem to affect use of the application.

The thread you linked to led me to JDK bug #[8274326](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8274326). My reading of this is that it's a bug in Java 17 that is fixed in 17.0.2. Have you already got that far and are you able to try the fix ?

Example error trace:

```
2021-12-04 16:52:20,162 [90933-ProcessLauncher-2] WARN  VASSAL.tools.logging.LoggedOutputStream - 2021-12-04 16:52:20.162 java[90935:21673463] (
    0   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x0000000105761d39 -[JavaComponentAccessibility accessibilityHitTest:withEnv:] + 153
    1   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000010570dd93 -[AWTView accessibilityHitTest:] + 179
    2   AppKit                              0x00007fff235fed71 -[NSWindow(NSWindowAccessibility) accessibilityHitTest:] + 309
    3   AppKit                              0x00007fff231a2d0c -[NSApplication(NSApplicationAccessibility) accessibilityHitTest:] + 342
    4   AppKit                              0x00007fff23173bf3 CopyElementAtPosition + 150
    5   HIServices                          0x00007fff257e7a2b _AXXMIGCopyElementAtPosition + 336
    6   HIServices                          0x00007fff25808708 _XCopyElementAtPosition + 369
    7   HIServices                          0x00007fff257c693c mshMIGPerform + 182
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20533a44 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 41
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20533925 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 619
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20531faf __CFRunLoopRun + 2400
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20530f8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
    12  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff28778a83 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
    13  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff287786b6 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 284
    14  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff28778583 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 70
    15  AppKit                              0x00007fff22d3a172 _DPSNextEvent + 864
    16  AppKit                              0x00007fff22d38945 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1364
    17  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000010592956a -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 122
    18  AppKit                              0x00007fff22d2ac69 -[NSApplication run] + 586
    19  libosxapp.dylib                     0x0000000105929339 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 185
    20  libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000010576a1b9 +[AWTStarter starter:headless:] + 505
    21  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000010592b00f +[ThreadUtilities invokeBlockCopy:] + 15
    22  Foundation                          0x00007fff212e2b81 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 204
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff205332bc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20533224 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 180
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20532fa4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 242
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff205319cc __CFRunLoopRun + 893
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff20530f8c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 563
    28  libjli.dylib                        0x0000000103476d32 CreateExecutionEnvironment + 402
    29  libjli.dylib                        0x0000000103472615 JLI_Launch + 1493
    30  java                                0x0000000103467c0e main + 414
    31  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff20456f3d start + 1
    32  ???                                 0x000000000000000f 0x0 + 15
```

Comment: I tried "brew upgrade java", but now I still can't upgrade to 17.0.2.

Answer (score 2):

On the GitHub page https://github.com/RaiMan/SikuliX1

There are notes related to "2.0.6 (branch release_2.0.x) preparing for release - snapshots available":

> Be aware:
>
> - Java 8 is no longer supported.
> - For macOS M1 (non-Intel) use the JDK's from Azul

The Azul OpenJDK build for the M1 chip is here:

https://www.azul.com/downloads/?os=macos&architecture=arm-64-bit&package=jdk

Try running on that OpenJDK build instead of https://github.com/openjdk (apologies if you're already running the Azul build)