# Bad JNI lookup accessibilityHitTest - What does this unexpected error message mean?

Tags: java, macos, java-native-interface

I am programming a banking application in Java.

Today surprisingly I get an error message, although I do no change to the code and it started perfectly before.

What does this error means ?

```
2022-07-22 09:56:40.685 java[12972:337712] Bad JNI lookup accessibilityHitTest
2022-07-22 09:56:40.686 java[12972:337712] (
    0   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000013c66dc50 -[CommonComponentAccessibility accessibilityHitTest:] + 180
    1   libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000013c62a78c -[AWTView accessibilityHitTest:] + 176
    2   AppKit                              0x00000001ab58b854 -[NSWindow(NSWindowAccessibility) accessibilityHitTest:] + 420
    3   AppKit                              0x00000001ab104ab0 -[NSApplication(NSApplicationAccessibility) accessibilityHitTest:] + 292
    4   AppKit                              0x00000001ab0d2180 CopyElementAtPosition + 160
    5   HIServices                          0x00000001add65340 _AXXMIGCopyElementAtPosition + 364
    6   HIServices                          0x00000001add89e28 _XCopyElementAtPosition + 356
    7   HIServices                          0x00000001add42d50 mshMIGPerform + 204
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a816d8c8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 60
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a816d784 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 604
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a816bc18 __CFRunLoopRun + 2372
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a816ab34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
    12  HIToolbox                           0x00000001b0daa338 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 292
    13  HIToolbox                           0x00000001b0daa0b4 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 564
    14  HIToolbox                           0x00000001b0da9e68 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 72
    15  AppKit                              0x00000001aacd251c _DPSNextEvent + 860
    16  AppKit                              0x00000001aacd0e14 -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 1328
    17  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000012eb50220 -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 144
    18  AppKit                              0x00000001aacc2fe0 -[NSApplication run] + 596
    19  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000012eb4ffd8 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 208
    20  libawt_lwawt.dylib                  0x000000013c68c674 +[AWTStarter starter:headless:] + 488
    21  libosxapp.dylib                     0x000000012eb51c50 +[ThreadUtilities invokeBlockCopy:] + 28
    22  Foundation                          0x00000001a9070f94 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 212
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a816d044 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a816cf90 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a816cc90 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a816b610 __CFRunLoopRun + 828
    27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a816ab34 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
    28  libjli.dylib                        0x0000000102f8efec CreateExecutionEnvironment + 400
    29  libjli.dylib                        0x0000000102f8b1fc JLI_Launch + 1184
    30  java                                0x0000000102e57bb0 main + 408
    31  dyld                                0x000000010303508c start + 520
)
Exception in thread "AppKit Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: accessibilityHitTest
```

Comment: It looks like your native code is trying to call a method on a java object that doesn't exist. Does `accessibilityHitTest` still exist?

Comment: yeah, it still exists. I get this error now on ever project, I created.

Comment: Did you try searching for _java accessibilityHitTest_ ? I found this: [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError：accessibilityHitTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70112706/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-accessibilityhittest). Are you getting the error on a Mac computer?

Comment: yes I use a MacBook. I already read it, but I those solutions does not change something